# Macports warning when installing automake: Warning: Deactivate forced. Proceeding despite dependencies

Tags: macports, automake

I just installed MacPorts and issued the command:

```
sudo port install automake
```

Throughout the process I see this message:

```
Warning: Deactivate forced.  Proceeding despite dependencies.
```

What does it mean?  Why did it happen?  Is it critical and, if so, should I do anything about it?

Thanks,
gb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based upon my own experience this is not critical and you should in most cases don't have to do anything about it. It is only a warning.

This warning is shown when an old version of a software package 'A' is uninstalled and replaced by a newer version, while another previously installed software package 'B' depends on it.
This package 'B' was built with the old version of package 'A' in mind, and might break if the newer version isn't compatible. However, for most updates this is not a problem.

(After upgrading packages you will notice that macports scans your files for linking errors, which, I believe, should detect this kind of problems and automatically fix them.)